# How to create relationship in RealmSwift?

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am less experienced in non relational database architecture. My use-case is as follows.

I have an Appointment, and Customer Realm object Model.

Appointment properties are 
`id` and `relatedCustomer`(Customer Model).
Customer properties are `id` and `name`

I fetch a list of appointments from server and it will add `relatedCustomer` in the Realm table as a relation of Appointment object.

Later, I fetch the list of customers from another API call and it will add more customers to the Customer Realm table.  After fetching the customer list data from server and before creating the customer realm objects, I clear all the previously saved customer objects to make sure that no orphan customer object(Customers that got deleted in the server but available in my realm cache) are displayed in the UI. This bulk deletion is removing my related customer of the Appointment.

How can I handle this?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is a use case that isn't straightforward in Realm.

I suggest that (if you haven't already done so) you make `id` on your customer model (I'll call it `Customer`) the [primary key property](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#primary-keys) for that model.

Once you do that, here's one possible solution.

When you fetch your list of customers from your server, I presume you'll get a JSON, XML, Swift dictionary, or similar data structure that'll contain a list of customers. From that list of customers, create a Swift `Set` of `id` strings, one for each customer.

Then use `Realm`'s `objects()` API to get a list of all the `Customer` objects in your Realm. You can then use Swift's `map()` method to turn that list of existing customers into a `Set` of `id` strings.

Now that you have two sets, you can use the `subtracting()` method on `Set` to get a list of all the `id`s that you need to remove (the `id`s for customers in your Realm, but not in your server data). Then you can remove those objects from the Realm.

Finally, you can use `Realm`'s `add(_:update:)` method to add all the new customers in, and update the existing users.

You may also want to investigate whether or not your server API could be changed to give you a list of users to delete relative to the list provided the last time you queried it.

Comment: This is a solution, I thought about. but my customer API cannot give all the customers at once. Pagination is applied in the customer API to improve the performance.

I think, to remove all the previously saved objects in Realm is the best approach. But it will remove the relatedCustomer relation of the Appointment. Is it a good idea to create a separate customer object for Appointment relation?